# Why I am not getting the "Redirected codes" using "requests" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried the following code to get the dead, redirected, alive URLs. But I am not getting the redirected URL response code.

I am sure about 302 code status from the browsers network view but not getting by the code. I even have specified instead of a range but did not work. My code records status code 200 instead of 302!

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import requests

def check_url_status(url):
"""Checks the status of a URL and returns a descriptive status string."""
try:
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
status_code = response.status_code
if status_code in range(200, 299):
return f"Alive ({status_code})"
elif status_code == 300:
return f"Multiple Choices Redirected ({status_code})"
elif status_code == 301:
return f"Moved Permanently Redirected ({status_code})"
elif status_code == 302:
return f"Temporarily Moved Redirected ({status_code})"
elif status_code in range(303, 400):
return f"Redirected ({status_code})"
else:
return f"Not Found ({status_code})"
except Exception as e:
return f"Error: {e}"

# Read URLs from CSV file
urls = []
with open("urls.csv", "r") as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
urls.append(row[0])

# Check each URL and write results to new file
with open("url_status.csv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["URL", "Status"])
for url in urls:
status = check_url_status(url)
writer.writerow([url, status])

print("URL status successfully written to url_status.csv!")
```

I tried to get the response code 200, 300, 500 etc. The above code records the 200 response code, even it could get the 500 but its not getting the 301,302 when list of urls are checking!

Comment: Probably it's following the redirect and you will have to tell your UA to not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. I have found the reason! By default I see the requests.get follows the redirected URLs and takes the status code 200! That is why I did not get the 300 codes!! I have disabled the redirect following by `allow_redirects=False`

So, the line number 6 of code was `response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)` and I changed to `response = requests.get(url, timeout=5, allow_redirects=False)`